# solve this $p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1} x \equiv 1 \pmod {p_n} $ with Wilson theorem for smallest integer answer , possible?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I try to solve this equation with the help of Wilson theorem $p_0=2 , p_1=3$
$$p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1} k \equiv 1 \pmod {p_n} $$

Wilson theorem :
$$(p_n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod {p_n} $$

lets first take equation with -1 instead of 1

$p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1} m \equiv -1 \pmod {p_n} $

so $m=\frac{(p_n-1)!}{p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1}}$

and we can say
$p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1} (m+k) \equiv 0 \pmod {p_n} $

so $m+k=p_n$
and from that $k=p_n-m$

at the end of that we can say
$$k=p_n-\frac{(p_n-1)!}{p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1}}$$
yes this is an answer but it is not the smallest positive integer , right?
but we can make it a smaller answer like this.
$$k'=p_n t+p_n-\frac{(p_n-1)!}{p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1}}$$
or with $s=t-1$
$$k'=p_n s-\frac{(p_n-1)!}{p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1}}$$

now we should fined a $s$ that make our answer smallest integer .

how we can fined that $s$ ?

Comment: That's a horribly inefficient way to compute the inverse of that prime product, since $(p_n-1)!$ will be (exponentially) huge. Is your goal to have a fast method to compute the inverse, or some useful closed form?

Comment: Is $p_j$ the $j$-th prime number ?

Comment: yes Peter it's $j-$th prime number @Peter

Comment: yes I know it's inefficient but I want some useful closed form to play with it . it is possible to do it with floor function but it's not playful , you know ?!  @BillDubuque